# Magento 2 - How to create admin configuration for a custom theme

Tags: magento2, configuration, design

I cannot find a tutorial to create admin configuration for a custom theme.
I need to create admin customization design and colors

Comment: It is not very clear you can give us more information? is this configuration must be changed on the admin? is it converge configuration that the templating of the admin ?if yes is better created a custom theme you can not act on the less file since the magento configuration

Answer (score 0):

That has been some time from when the question was made, but for record for those searching for the answer this might help:

https://www.magetop.com/blog/how-to-create-simple-module-to-configure-options-for-theme-in-magento-2/